# How do you return from a function at an arbitrary point?

Tags: elisp, functions

How do you return early from a function before it's ended? For example:

```
(defun my-func () 
 "for example."
 (unless something (return nil))
 ; continue as usual...
 (+ 42 1))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to what @EmacsFodder covered, just raise an error.

This will not help if the code is called within (dynamically, not lexically) the extent of error-handling constructs such as `ignore-errors` or `condition-case`, but otherwise it is a fine way to exit a function. It is in fact what is done most of the time.

```el
(defun my-func () 
 "..."
 (unless something (error "Whoops!"))
 ; continue as usual...
 (+ 42 1))
```

If you want to handle the error yourself then you can put the calling code (e.g. the call to something that ulimately calls `my-func`) inside a `condition-case`.
Again, this is what is done most of the time, at least as often as using `catch` + `throw`. It all depends on what behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Drew, I agree this is quite a common method.  However, just doing an early return in a lot of other languages, doesn't incur the _complexity_ of having to then deal with an error.   When researching the question/answer set.  I was specifically looking for alternatives to the "erroring out" style which always feels kludgy to me.  I didn't specify this explicitly in the question text mind you.

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do. If you want to end immediately, with no further processing/handling, then raising an error is a good way to go for a nonlocal exit, in Emacs. If you want to do something during a nonlocal exit, i.e., handle it in some way, then `catch`, `unwind-protect`, `condition-case` and the like are useful. There is a whole section of the Elisp manual devoted to [nonlocal exits](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Nonlocal-Exits.html). (And there is nothing particularly kludgy about any of them, IMO.)

Comment: "Feels" is entirely subjective of course.  Thanks for the nonlocal manual ref.

Answer (score 27):

We have a number of options available.  In general, what you are looking for is a "nonlocal exit"; see [`(info "(elisp) Nonlocal Exits")`](https://gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Nonlocal-Exits.html).

### Throw

You can `catch` / `throw` to exit the function with a value.  See [`(info "(elisp) Catch and Throw")`](https://gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Catch-and-Throw.html) for details.

example:

```el
(defun my-func ()
  "Simplistic `catch'/`throw' example."
  (catch 'my-early-return
    (when t
      (throw 'my-early-return "this is the short-circuit result of catch"))
    "this is the fallback result of catch"))
```

### Block

You can also use `cl-block` and `cl-return-from` (although you will need to require `cl-lib`).  See [`(info "(cl) Blocks and Exits")`](https://gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Blocks-and-Exits.html) for details.

example:

```el
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'cl-lib))

(defun my-func ()
  "Simplistic `cl-block'/`cl-return-from' example."
  (cl-block my-func
    (when t
      (cl-return-from my-func))
    (1+ 42)))
```

### cl-defun

We also have `cl-defun` which has an implicit `cl-block` with the same name as the function, so we can use the `cl-block` style with less typing.

example:

```el
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'cl-lib))

(cl-defun my-func ()
  "Simplistic `cl-defun' implicit block example."
  (when t
    (cl-return-from my-func)) ; `my-func' is an implicit block.
  (+ 42 1))
```

### defun*

In old Emacsen, specifically Emacs 24.2 and earlier, `cl-defun` was provided as `defun*` by the now-obsolete library `cl.el`.

example:

```el
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'cl))

(defun* my-func ()
  "Simplistic `defun*' implicit block example."
  (when t
    (return-from my-func)) ; `my-func' is an implicit block.
  (+ 42 1))
```

Note, however, that in Emacsen that old you can instead install `cl-lib` as a compatibility layer from GNU[-devel] ELPA:

- https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/cl-lib.html
- https://elpa.gnu.org/devel/cl-lib.html

Comment: Note that if you don't have a preference for the CL syntax, `catch`/`throw` is more idiomatic in elisp, as other approaches are ultimately implemented in terms of catch/throw. The elisp manual says: "Most other versions of Lisp, including Common Lisp, have several ways of transferring control nonsequentially: `return`, `return-from`, and `go`, for example.  Emacs Lisp has only `throw`."